# How can i include php file from blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello Guys In Laravel Blade I Want To Include Php file i try to use `@include` but it doesn't work because `@include` to include views not php file

My File I Want To Include

**App\Helpers\Variables.php**

```
$dufaultLang = get_dufault_lang();
$categories =
    mainCategory::where(
        'translation_lang',

        $dufaultLang
    )
        -> Selection()  // Select From Selection Scope
        -> get();       // Get Selection Data
```

**MyBlade**

```
<ul class="menu level1">

@include('App.Helpers.Variables.php') // Here It Doesn't Work

@if(isset($categories) && $categories -> count() > 0)

@foreach($categories as $category)
Hello
@endforeach

@endif

</ul>
```

I Can't  Include The `$Categories` From Variables.php I Try To Use @include but I see This Error

```
View [App.Helpers.Variables.php] not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

In AppServiceProvider boot method

```
public function boot()
{
  $dufaultLang = get_dufault_lang();
  $categories =mainCategory::where('translation_lang', $dufaultLang)
                -> Selection()  
                -> get();       
  View::share('categories', $categories);
}
```

and in your view

```
<ul class="menu level1">
    @if(isset($categories) && $categories->count() > 0)

        @foreach($categories as $category)
            Hello
        @endforeach
    @endif

</ul>
```

Also, make sure to follow the naming convention for the model class

As suggested by @Snapey in the comment, to avoid executing a query every time, you can use [Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache) to store the query result

Comment: Does this  code share the variable to all views

Comment: @Laravel yes it will share to all view

Comment: Thank You I'l Try if work i'l accept Your Answer

Comment: be careful with this because it will run on every view file, including headers / footers etc. You could find your database query being run over and over.  Either cache the results or be specific about which view files it should be shared into.

Comment: @Snapey yes agree.Caching will be helpful  here